# is there a specific asp.net core configuration for CORS to work in angular with multiple APIs

Tags: c#, angular, iis, asp.net-core, cors

I'm new with asp.net core and angular and I have some problems with CORS.
I searched and I almost reach my goals but I still have a problem for a specific case.

Here are the steps followed:
I start with angular template as describe in [this article](https://www.talkingdotnet.com/create-an-angular-7-app-with-visual-studio-2017/)

I create a very simple api controller to retrieve roles for current user, here is my simplified code :

```
[Authorize()]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class PermissionController : Controller
{
    private List<Tuple<string, string>> roles = new List<Tuple<string, string>> { new Tuple<string, string>("Admin", "Role_AutHab_Dev_Administrateur"), new Tuple<string, string>("Gest", "Role_AutHab_Dev_Gestionnaire") };

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        bool test = false;
        List<string> lst = new List<string>();

        foreach (var item in roles)
        {
            test = User.IsInRole(item.Item2);
            if (test)
                lst.Add(item.Item1);
        }

        return lst.ToArray();
    }
```

`To solved [this problem](https://github.com/aspnet/CORS/issues/60) with CORS in ASPNet Core, I allowed anonymous mode and windows mode in my c# project properties and configure my startup class like this :`

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    }

    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
    app.UseCors(o => o.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowCredentials());
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });

    app.UseSpa(spa =>
    {
        // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
        // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

        spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
        }
    });
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors();

    services.AddAuthentication(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

    // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
    services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
    {
        configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
    });
}
```

At this point, all work fine.
The problem comes when I use another API that provides me the business data.
When I run my project with IIS Express (with visual studio) or with IIS after a publish, queries failed with CORS error in chrome console tab but work fine in chrome network tab !
like this :
[image: Imgur]
[image: Imgur]
[image: Imgur]

I think the problem comes from the anonymous mode because I tried calling my second API through my Permission Controller and it works fine (with the Authorize attribute) but I can't do that for all methods !

Any idea ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: @FabianH. Thanks, but I already read this article and applied his content, you can see in screenshot that CORS work fine

Comment: It is in your first, but not your second screenshot. What's the difference between the two?

Comment: @FabianH.The first is the OPTION query to ask permission and the second is the final GET query because the first return OK with CORS specifics headers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after long hours of questioning my project angular or asp.net core, I went to see my project api and I found that only localhost: 4200 was authorized as origin!
All those hours of lost search for a simple missing configuration ... grrrr